# azure b2c custom policy failed to get access token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new to Azure B2C. This is the file called "trustframeworkextension.xml" that I'm using.

After I logged in through my identity provider (IDP), I received a error message saying, "Message: Basic credentials specified for 'REST-AcquireAccessTokenForGraph' are invalid. Check that the credentials are correct and that access has been granted by the resource."

Can you help me fix this issue?

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="testingorganization.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" PublicPolicyUri="http://testingorganization.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" TenantObjectId="da0052bc-b835-4855-bc14-df4cb987c518">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>testing.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="groups">
        <DisplayName>Collection of group membership IDs</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="group_1">
        <DisplayName>Group 1</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="group_2">
        <DisplayName>Group 2</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="group_3">
        <DisplayName>Group 3</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="isMemberOfAllowGroup">
        <DisplayName>isMemberOfAllowGroup</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="grant_type">
        <DisplayName>Grant type</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="scope">
        <DisplayName>scope</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="bearerToken">
        <DisplayName>Bearer token</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="responseMsg">
        <DisplayName>Error</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddGroup_1" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group_1" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddGroup_2" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group_2" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddGroup_3" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group_3" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CheckIfMemberOfAllowGroup" TransformationMethod="StringCollectionContains">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="admins" />
          <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isMemberOfAllowGroup" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">facebook_clientid</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">Proxyapplicationid</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">identityid</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="Proxyapplicationid" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="identityid" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!-- SAML Token Issuer technical profile -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Saml2AssertionIssuer">
          <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
          <OutputTokenFormat>SAML2</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IssuerUri">testauth</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_testSAMLCert" />
            <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_testSAMLCert" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-issuer" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Session management technical profile for SAML-based tokens -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-Saml-issuer">
          <DisplayName>Session Management Provider</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.SamlSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AcquireAccessTokenForGraph">
          <DisplayName>Acquire Token</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/testingorganization.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSGraphClientId" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSGraphClientSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Call Microsoft Graph API to get group claims-->
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <!--UserJourneys>
    
    </UserJourneys-->
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Have you configured [App Insights traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)? You could get more info on the error from there.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#cryptographic-keys).

It is much simpler than what you have.

Can you log in as a user with that username and password? i.e. are the credentials correct?

For your input claims, are you using "client_credentials"  as an input parameter or as a flow?

This is not how you invoke a [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) flow.

Comment: Can you log in as a user with that username and password ? Yes
are you using "client_credentials" as an input parameter or as a flow ? Yes

Answer (score 0):

only issue was my CryptographicKeys are expired.

```
<CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSGraphClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSGraphClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy